# Oracle Type Error with Select Into

Tags: oracle

I'm using Oracle 10g and I'm getting some issues with codes that are suppose to work. It's driving me crazy. The code goes like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trig_t1
AFTER INSERT ON t1
DECLARE
    count1 INTEGER;
    foo t1.field1%TYPE; --field is a VARCHAR2(20)
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO count1 --error in this line
    FROM t1
    WHERE condition;

    foo:='bar';

    UPDATE t1 SET field1=foo --error in this line
    WHERE some condition ;
END;
```

It "compiles with errors", all are of the type of "PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type".
I just don't get it... Does anybody know what's wrong with my code?

Comment: The issue was in the conditions on the statements. Thanks anymawy for your replay.

Answer (score 2):

Can you post the definition of `T1`?  Your code seems to work fine for me if `T1` has a single column named `FIELD1`.  Is it possible that you have a column in the table that shares the name with a local variable?

```
SQL> create table t1( field1 varchar2(20) );

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_t1
  2    after insert on t1
  3  declare
  4    l_count1 integer;
  5    foo      t1.field1%type;
  6  begin
  7    select count(*)
  8      into l_count1
  9      from t1;
 10
 11    foo := 'bar';
 12
 13    update t1
 14       set field1 = foo
 15     where 1=1;
 16  end;
 17  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into t1 values( 'foo' );

1 row created.

SQL> select * from t1;

FIELD1
--------------------
bar
```